# Import webpage data to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I really need some help. I'm trying to import some data from a webpage into Excel. Creating a new query to get the data from the webpage doesn't work. I believe this is due to the website not containing tables of data. I am trying to extract a single figure from the webpage.

I have tried to use VBA to get the number from the webpage but my coding skills are very limited so haven't been successful. I'm unable to attach a picture of the webpage so I've tried to give you enough info below. The data I need is the 17387:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="unit-count total ">17387</td>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Please include your code and explain what isn't working.